# How to: grid-array of primitives in pyglet and dynamic filling of shapes

Tags: python, arrays, opengl, pyglet

I am trying to visualize the network load in a network simulation tool. I want to display the network nodes as a grid of squares in a window (e.g. a 4x4 mesh network) where I can individually pick the fill-color for each square based on the traffic across the node (the traffic info has to be read from a dump file but thats for later). I am trying to see if I can use pyglet for this. So, for example, lets say we have a 2x2 network (4 squares). I want a 2x2 matrix of squares where I can change the fill-color of each element individually. I am beginner and so far I have learnt to draw a single filled square after looking up a lot of references. See the code:

```
import sys, time, math, os, random
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()

label = pyglet.text.Label('Simulation', 
                          font_name='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size=16,
                          color=(204,204,0,255),      #red font (255,0,0) opacity=255
                          x=window.width, y=window.height,
                          anchor_x='right', anchor_y='top') 

class FilledSquare:
    def __init__(self, width, height, xpos, ypos):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.angle = 0
        self.size = 1
        x = width/2.0
        y = height/2.0
        self.vlist = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4, ('v2f', [-x,-y, x,-y, -x,y, x,y]), ('t2f', [0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1]), ('c3B',(0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0)))
    def draw(self,w,h,x,y):
        self.width=w
        self.height=h
        self.xpos=x
        self.ypos=y
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(self.xpos, self.ypos, 0)
        self.vlist.draw(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)        
        glPopMatrix()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    glClearColor(0, 0.3, 0.5, 0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    label.draw()
    square1.draw(60,60,460,240)


square1 = FilledSquare(30, 30, 100, 200)
pyglet.app.run()
```

1. I think in this way, the fill-color is static as it is initialized. How can I pass the fill-color?
2. How to create a 2D array of FilledSquare (maybe something like square[i][j] which I can access in a loop.

Let me know if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some suggestions from Adam in the pyglet-users google group. Here they are:

1. As you're using immediate mode anyway you might as well not pass the vertex colour as part of your vertex list but use glColor* to set the colour before drawing e.g.

   > glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
2. You can put objects into a list so you could have

> squares = [[FilledSquare(...), FilledSquare(...)], [FilledSquare(...), FilledSquare(...)]]

Thanks Adam (if you see this), it really helped.